# I am trying to add a verification step on laravel auth but its giving me an error Swift_TransportException (530)

Tags: php, laravel

I added a laravel auth onto my project, now I am trying to add a verification step so that when user registers it takes them to a page where they are asked to verify email. I have followed the laravel way of doing add, added the following auth to my home controller

```
$this->middleware('auth');
$this->middleware('verified');
```

After adding that to my controller I modified my Auth routes to this

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

In My User class I added the following code

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
```

just added the implements MustVerifyEmail to the class.
After this it suppose to be working but I am getting the following areas

```
Swift_TransportException (530)
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required "

$this->middleware('auth');
$this->middleware('verified');
```

After adding that to my controller i modified my Auth routes to this

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

In My User class I added the following code

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
```

just added the implements MustVerifyEmail to the class.
after this it suppose to be working but i am getting the following areas

```
Swift_TransportException (530)
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required "
```

This is my User class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

This is my Home controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('verified');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

I am expecting that when a user registers it is suppose to take a use to a page that requires them to verify the email.

Comment: How are you sending the email? This `Swift_TransportException` is an error generated when the server cannot send an email. Check that your mail sending method is what you need, and that if you're using credentials, they exist and are correct. Settings should be in `.env` and `config/mail.php`

Comment: I would like for it to log the link in my log files for now

Comment: The putting `MAIL_DRIVER=log` in your `.env` should suffice. It's likely set to something that requires a username/password for authentication, like `gmail` or `mailgun`, etc. Might have to update `env` cache if you're using it (`php artisan config:cache`)

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked just fine..